# Как при выборе чекбокса у родительской ссылки менять надпись

Tags: javascript, css

Есть список с чекбоксами. Как мне менять текст в ссылке, при активации этого чекбокса, на текст с кол-вом активных чекбоксов?

Верстка:

```js
var countChecked = function() {
  var n = $('input:checked').length;
  if (n != 0)
    $('#price').html("выбрано " + n + '<span class="caret">').addClass("activedrop");

};
countChecked();

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', countChecked);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="col-md-11">
    <ul id="ddmenu">
      <li><a href="#" class="open">Тест<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <div class="hover">
          <div class="scroll">
            <label>
                      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="test[]"  value="1">
                      <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
                      <span class="label">Тест</span>
                    </label>
            <label>
                      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="test[]"  value="1">
                      <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
                      <span class="label">Тест</span>
                    </label>
            <label>
                      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="test[]"  value="1">
                      <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
                      <span class="label">Тест</span>
                    </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Неактивный чекбокс:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Активный:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же при повторном клике, как снимаем чекбокс, остается изменения у ссылки с кол-вом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проблема в чем? в том что когда потворно кликаем текст показывает что один выбран?

Comment: @JurijJazdanov Да,еще что этих ссылок много,т.е.
Есть 3 ссылки с чекбоксами,у этих ссылок есть класс .open.
При выборе чекбоса стоит ид #price,т.е. если мы выбрали чекбоксы НЕ в ссылке под #price,то будет отображаться кол-во в ссылке #price,хотя мы выбирали чекбоксы НЕ в ней.
Если же поменять #price на селектор класса .open,то изменения будут у всех ссылок,а нужно менять только у ссылке под которой были активны чекбоксы.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let lis = Array.from ( document.querySelectorAll( 'li' ) );
    
lis.forEach( ( li ) => {
  let link = Array.from( li.children ).find( ( el ) => {
    if ( el.tagName === 'A' && el.className === 'open' ) {
      return el;
    }
    return false;
  } );

  li.counter = 0;
  li.addEventListener( 'change', ( e ) => {
    link.innerHTML = `Выбрано ${ e.srcElement.checked ?
                                   ++li.counter :
                                   --li.counter }`;    
  } );
} );
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="col-md-11">
    <ul id="ddmenu">
      <li><a href="#" class="open">Тест<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <div class="hover">
          <div class="scroll">
            <label>
                  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="test[]"  value="1">
                  <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
                  <span class="label">Тест</span>
                </label>
            <label>
                  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="test[]"  value="1">
                  <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
                  <span class="label">Тест</span>
                </label>
            <label>
                  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="test[]"  value="1">
                  <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
                  <span class="label">Тест</span>
                </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
<li><a href="#" class="open">Тест<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <div class="hover">
          <div class="scroll">
            <label>
                  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="test[]"  value="1">
                  <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
                  <span class="label">Тест</span>
                </label>
            <label>
                  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="test[]"  value="1">
                  <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
                  <span class="label">Тест</span>
                </label>
            <label>
                  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="test[]"  value="1">
                  <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
                  <span class="label">Тест</span>
                </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var countChecked = function() {
  var n = $('input:checked').length;
  if (n > 0){
    $('#price')
      .html("Выбрано " + n + '<span class="caret">')
      .addClass("activedrop");
  } else {
    $('#price')
      .html("Тест")
      .removeClass("activedrop");
  }
};

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', countChecked);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="col-md-11">
    <ul id="ddmenu">
      <li><a href="#" class="open" id="price">Тест<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <div class="hover">
          <div class="scroll">
            <label>
                      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="test[]"  value="1">
                      <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
                      <span class="label">Тест</span>
                    </label>
            <label>
                      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="test[]"  value="1">
                      <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
                      <span class="label">Тест</span>
                    </label>
            <label>
                      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="test[]"  value="1">
                      <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
                      <span class="label">Тест</span>
                    </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ,Но у вас меняется только ссылка с #price
У меня есть несколько li>a и у всех разные Id,вы сделали только для прайс,а как сделать универсально,чтобы на все li>a распространялся ЖС?Если поставить селектор класса,то они будут все меняться.
Мне же нужно,чтобы при активации чекбокса,соответстующая ссылка(родитель) менялась